# How to change wordpress theme menu search .svg icon to custom png

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, themes

I have an issue with a wordpress theme top menu search icon, I want to change it to a custom .png file saying "book now", and change it's function from an search form that is currently opening, to a simple url to open the store page in the website.

The theme is the following https://themes.waituk.com/entrada-default/

I've managed to figure the search icon is an svg file while fiddling with chrome's network tools and the theme styles.css file, but found the search icon being mentioned several times throughout the file and wasn't sure which one references it, or if I need to change something in another file in the theme structure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to see icomoon.css(line 814), it will have .icon-search:before

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see from the link you shared, there are basically 2 things that need to be understood here:

1- The Icon.
I couldn't find any reference to a svg file, may be the downloadable theme is different from the demo page you have shared. In this case, the search icon is being generated by a plugin called "icomoon" (https://icomoon.io/), so I suggest to change the span class "icon icon-search" to a new class with a custom css for your new png icon.

2- The search function

The search function is also being called by what appears to be a plugin, in a function at jquery.main.js:

```
// apply search plugin
$body.search({
        hideOnClickOutside: false,
        menuActiveClass: 'search-active',
        menuOpener: '.search-opener',
        menuDrop: '.form-group'
    });
```

Here you will need to change the a class "search-opener" to something else or comment out this function before modifying the link as you want. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, didn't need the full solution as for design purposes the "book now" button was changed to a notification bar plugin, however, your solution was extremely helpful to remove the search icon and form.